# Command raised an exception: TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword for embed

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I don't know where the error is. I have a GIveAway command that works if I type anything in a normal string format, but if I try to embed it again. it doesn't work. help please?:

**Code:**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def gstart(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Answer These Questions you only have 25 Seconds!")

    questions = ["Which channel should it be hosted in?",
                "What should be the duration of the giveaway? (s/m/h/d)",
                "What is the prize of the giveaway?"]

    answers = []

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    for i in questions:
        await ctx.send(i)

        try:
            msg = await client.wait_for("message", timeout=25.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send("You didn't answer in time, Please be faster! Retard")
            return
        else:
            answers.append(msg.content)

    
    try:
        c_id = int(answers[0][2:-1])
    except:
        await ctx.send(f"You did not mention a channel properly, Do it like this {ctx.channel.mention} next time.")
        return

    channel = client.get_channel(c_id)

    time = convert(answers[1])
    if time == -1:
        await ctx.send(f"You didn't answer the time with a  proper unit. Use (s/m/h/d).")
        return
    elif time == 2:
        await ctx.send(f"The time must be an intger (number). Please enter in a number.")
        return
    prize = answers[2]

    await ctx.send(f"The GiveAway will be in {channel.mention} and will last {answers[1]} seconds!")

    embed = discord.Embed(title = "GiveAway! ", description = f"{prize}", color = random.choice(mycolor))

    embed.add_field(name = "Hosted by:", value = ctx.author.mention)

    embed.set_footer(text = f"Ends {answers[1]} from now!")

    my_msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)

    await my_msg.add_reaction("")

    await asyncio.sleep(time)

    new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)

    users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    users.pop(users.index(client.user))

    winner = random.choice(users)
    
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"We have a GiveAway winner", color = random.choice(mycolor))  #here 

    em.set_author(name=f"Congrats {winner.mention}")  #here
    em.add_field(name=f"{winner.mention} WON:", value=f"{prize}!")  #here
    em.set_footer(text=f"Organized by {ctx.author.mention}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)  #here


    await ctx.send(em=em)  #so this doesn't work but if I do channel.send("example") it works
```

**Error:**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Ignoring exception in command gstart:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\almaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\almaj\OneDrive\Documents\3mbot\main code\mbot.py", line 619, in gstart
    await ctx.send(em=em)
TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'em'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\almaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\almaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\almaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'em'
```

---

I've tried ctx.send channel.send ctx.channel.send.... Nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not `em` it's `embed`

```py
await ctx.send(embed=em)
```